Laravel Rate limiter clear is not working
I have this rate limiter in route service provider file :
protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('login-customer', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinutes(5,3)->by($request->ip());
        });
    }

And my route is :
Route::post('login-tenant', [LoginCustomerController::class, 'login'])->name('tenant_login')->middleware(['throttle:login-customer']);

And my method is :
protected function clearLoginAttempts(Request $request)
    {

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey($request));
    }

    protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->ip();
    }
    public function login(CustomerSendSMSRequest $request)
    {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

Explanation :
The idea is that I need to make rate limiter of only validation problem or response not successful.
Problem :
But when I try to clear the rate limiter after successful response the rate limiter does not cleared.
Expecting
I am expecting that rate limiter not hitting the successful response (like clear it if it's successful response)
